# Better Javascript performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api, howler.js

I'm currently building an app in React to learn the language. The App is a game and within the game i'm playing a lot of sounds using the [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/). Howler is great as it allows me to easily create sounds and also very importantly allows me to adjust the pitch of a sound meaning I can create melodies with just one sample.

The issue i'm starting to run into when I have a lot of different sounds at different pitches going on is performance. With the code I have setup to loop over my sound object is quite heavy and I am wondering if there is a way to optimize it (i'm by no means a Javascript expert so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a much leaner way to execute the sound object). Anyway here is my sound object below to give you an idea:

```
var testTrack = [{
        rowId:1,
        rowExtras:"notExpanded",
        rowSample:
            {
                sampleId:"1",
                notes:[
                    {
                        keyNumber:0,
                        noteDelay:0,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:2,
                        noteDelay:460,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:4,
                        noteDelay:920,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:6,
                        noteDelay:1380,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:8,
                        noteDelay:1840,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:10,
                        noteDelay:2300,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:12,
                        noteDelay:2760,
                        notePitch:1
                    },{
                        keyNumber:14,
                        noteDelay:3220,
                        notePitch:1
                    }                               
                ],
                sampleName:"Heavy Kick",
                sampleSource:"../../samplesWav/sample1.wav"
            }  

        },{    ...there are 12 more objects in the array with different samples in them
```

Here is the code I use to loop over and play the sound with Howler.js. Please note the above object lives in my Apps state under this.state.trackObject:

```
  playTrack(){

    var audioArray = this.state.trackObject;

    for(var i=0; i <= audioArray.length - 1; i++) {

        var rowObject = this.state.trackObject[i]

        var notesLength = rowObject.rowSample.notes.length

        for(var j=0; j <= notesLength - 1; j++) {
            var notes = rowObject.rowSample.notes[j].noteDelay;
            var id = rowObject.rowSample.sampleId;
            var src = rowObject.rowSample.sampleSource; 
            var pitch = rowObject.rowSample.notes[j].notePitch;

            playSample(id,notes,src,pitch)                
        }

    }

    function playSample(id,notes,src,pitch){

        if(id != "null"){
        setTimeout(function(){  

        //this is where howler is used
         var sound = new Howl({
              src: [src],
              rate:pitch
         })

         sound.play();                 

         }, notes);  
      }
   }


}
```

I'm try to do thing as much as I can in the 'React' way but i'm still learning so not sure if there would be a better way to intergrate the play function with my Apps state for better browser performance.

I've thought about using Audio sprites (which actually are setup to work quite well in Howler). I tried using this one [here](https://github.com/tonistiigi/audiosprite) . I actually had an installation issue and coudln't get it running but even if I managed to fix that then I don't think I could add sounds with a pitch bend applied from howlers API to the sprite?

Thanks and I welcome any suggestions on performance/ solutions anyone might have!

Comment: One micro-optimization you could make that wouldn't have any noticeable impact on performance but could help with maintainability would be to move the assignment of `src` and `id` out of the `j` loop to the place where `notesLength` is created. They only change when `i` changes, so there is no need to reread/rewrite them every time `j` loops. Also if you ever change to using `let` instead of `var` moving them to the proper scope would also probably prevent some GC slow down, since with `let` you will be constantly creating and destroying variables because `let` is block scoped.

Comment: Just FYI, the current version of audiosprite is broken, try using the previous version. Also, you should have no issue manipulating pitch on individual sprites with howler.

Comment: Thanks James, is there a way you can recommend to change the pitch of the audio but in a way that transposes the sound? ie makes the pitch higher/ lower but keeps the sample length the same? Also i've tried a new approach for my performance issues here: https://jsfiddle.net/xs5Lu4db/ not sure if you can recommend a leaner way than this? It's the best I could come up with..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your game works, but perhaps you don't need to iterate over the entire array. If you store the sounds in a hash, and access them by some unique identifier(maybe the sound name?), this should improve performance dramatically.

So instead of instead of declaring testTrack as an array like this ...

```
var testTrack = [{
  rowId:1,
  rowExtras:"notExpanded",
  rowSample: { // Code removed for brevity }
},{
  rowId:2,
  rowExtras:"notExpanded",
  rowSample: { // Code removed for brevity }
}];
```

Declare it like this ...

```
var testTrack = {
  "track1": {
    rowId:1,
    rowExtras: "notExpanded",
    rowSample: { }
  },
  "track2": {
    rowId:2,
    rowExtras:"notExpanded",
    rowSample: { }
  }
};
```

Then access the elements using one of the methods below, where "track1" would be the sound name ...

```
var myTrack = testTrack.track1;
var myTrack = testTrack['track1'];
```

Not sure if this makes sense in the context of your game, but this will at least save you iterating the entire loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that would prevent me from looping over the "outer" forloop but I would still have to loop over the notes array, unless there would be a way around this aswell?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate the notes array within the context of the game? What does iterating the notes actually mean? Is there anything preventing you from using a hash instead of the inner array as well?

Comment: Basicaly the notes are dynamic based off user input (its a music game). So when the user clicks a series of butons, depending on the button it will assign a certain sound and also different notes for that sound (again the notes depend on what button the user has clicked and the variable assigned to that note will have a unique delay and optional pitch (or rate) change. This is why I need a way to loop over the sounds - because they are dynamic based of user input. Not sure if there is a way I could store the function for each sound before the user clicks play to save performance while playing?

Comment: Are the sounds/notes defined somewhere, like in a database? If so, then you should be able to use the unique identifier for the sound as a key, and render it in a hash. This way you can access the sounds via their unique key(i.e. the PK in the database). If they are not defined in a database, then you need a way to uniquely identify each one on the client side. Regardless if you store these in a database, or on the client side, you need to find a way to assign a unique identifier to each sound, so that you can access it directly, without having to iterate over the entire loop.